# is there a way to make interaction button that dismisses an ephemeral message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to create an ephemeral confirmation message in a Discord bot and when the user clicks cancel, it should dismiss the message.

[image]

Code:

```
 await interaction.deferReply({ephemeral:true});
        const cancelButton = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger)
        .setEmoji("✖️")
        .setCustomId("cancelclose");
        const confirmButton = new ButtonBuilder()
        .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Primary)
        .setEmoji("✔️")
        .setCustomId("close");
        const rowe = new ActionRowBuilder()
        .addComponents(cancelButton,confirmButton);
        const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle(`Are you sure?`)
            .setColor('#653386')
            .setFooter({ text: `${config.sendPanel.footerText}`, iconURL: `${guild.iconURL()}` });
        await interaction.editReply({embed:[embed],components:[rowe],ephemeral:true});
```

Comment: You can delete the ephemeral message itself

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can dismiss a message by deleting its reply.

- #### Deleting the `initial` reply:

```js
interaction.deleteReply();
```

- #### Deleting a specific reply:

```js
const msg = await interaction.reply({
    content: 'Hello World!'
});

interaction.deleteReply(msg);
```

Reference: [CommandInteraction#deleteReply](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/CommandInteraction?scrollTo=deleteReply)